# Material UI textField default value not showing

Tags: reactjs, forms, material-ui, textfield, default-value

This issue is happening with an update form textField. First I have fetched data with the toDo id.

```
const [toDo, setTodo] = useState<any>({});
useEffect(() => {
axiosConfig
  .get(`/todo/${todoId}`)
  .then((response) => {
    setTodo(response.data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    setError(true);
  });}, [todoId]);
```

Then I created an array of object like this,

```
const { title, details, category } = toDo;
const textFields = [
{ name: "title", value: title },
{ name: "details", value: details },
{ name: "category", value: category },];
```

Finally, I have created a textField and mapped it like this,

```
{textFields.map((el) => (
              <TextField
                fullWidth
                key={el.name}
                defaultValue={el.value}
                label={_.startCase(el.name)}
                name={el.name}
                onChange={(e) => handleSetFormState(e)}
              />
            ))}
```

Now the problem is default value is not showing in the input field. It's working with the normal jsx input field. But, Not working with MUI textField.

If anyone knows the solution. Please let me know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried making sure that textFields array does have the data in the value property?

If your textfields doesn't show anything as a default value it mostly mean that the value in question are undefined and I think you should be looking in your axiosConfig request.
I use fetch instead of axios so I always convert the response in the frontend to json using the **.json()** function but I see In Axios responses are already served as javascript object.

My guess is that you should make sure in the backend you have the right data and that you send them to the client in a json format and that you have the right data object in Axios:

```
.then((response) => {
    setTodo(response.data);
})
```

Hope this help.